# bottomNavigationBar not showing up - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a bottom navigation bar widget in the Scaffold but for some unknown reason, the content of the widget (bottomNavigationBar) is not appearing up

Here is my code

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

  final TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Title'.toUpperCase()),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row( // Nothing showing up
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: messageController,
            autofocus: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Message',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))
              )
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            style: ButtonStyle(
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.redAccent)
            ),
            child: Text('Send'.toUpperCase()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a row as the child of your bottomNamvigationBar

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Row( // Nothing showing up ...)
```

You need to have as the child: BottomNavigationBar(items:[])

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
```